# What is the importance of getting MuleSoft Certified for a Salesforce Developer?

Tags: mulesoft

I am planning to prepare for 'MCD - Integration and API Associate' certification, I have no idea about what MuleSoft is!! I would appreciate if someone can enlighten me about, how this certification preparation is going to be helpful for being a **Salesforce Developer**.

Thanks,
Nachiket

Answer (score 1):

One of the prominent products of Mulesoft is MuleESB that can be used to integrate many systems including Salesforce with other systems. It includes create a http endpoint which can be used to other system to perform an operation like fetch a order details from SAP system using SFDC opportunity Id.

I do not belive it will help you going a better salesforce developer however you will get a hold of integration concepts which may help you moving forward.